# How to set a method to a JavaFX Alert Button

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I want to give the buttons "OK" and "Cancel" a method, which will be execute, when the user clicks on one of these buttons:

[image: Alert Box]

How can I do this with my code?

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Test");
alert.setHeaderText("This is a test.");
alert.setResizable(false);
alert.setContentText("Select okay or cancel this alert.");
alert.showAndWait();
```

In my theory, the code to set an action for one of the buttons looks like this:

```
alert.setActionForButtonOK(OkMethod());
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `alert#showAndWait` returns an Optional containing the button that has been pressed (or `null` if the no button has been pressed and the dialoge is exited). Use that result to choose which operation you would like to run. E.g.

```
Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if(!result.isPresent())
    // alert is exited, no button has been pressed.
else if(result.get() == ButtonType.OK)
     //oke button is pressed
else if(result.get() == ButtonType.CANCEL)
    // cancel button is pressed
```

Comment: showAndWait is not allowed during animation or layout processing

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to register event handlers to the button (and btw the `Dialog` class is not designed to provide direct access to it's buttons). You can simply check the value returned by `showAndWait` to get the button that was pressed by the user and act accordingly:

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Test");
alert.setHeaderText("This is a test.");
alert.setResizable(false);
alert.setContentText("Select okay or cancel this alert.");

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
ButtonType button = result.orElse(ButtonType.CANCEL);

if (button == ButtonType.OK) {
    System.out.println("Ok pressed");
} else {
    System.out.println("canceled");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, dialogs usually just collect an input and code taking action on that input does so based on looking at what the dialog return value is.  **Usually.**  There are many reasons for exceptions, however.  A custom dialog may need to validate an input field before allowing dismissal, for example, or the buttons may be used to invoke control actions, etc...

Within your dialog class, you can do this:

```
final Button btnFoo = (Button) dialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton( buttonTypeFoo );
```

Then it's just a matter of adding an event handler hook.  Remember to consume the event if you don't want the click to dismiss the dialog for whatever reason:

```
btnFoo.setOnAction( event -> {
      onBtnFooClicked();
      event.consume();
    } );
```

Comment: event.consume() in setOnAction handler doesn't prevent  close dialog